# How to extend a React component without declaring render() in child?

Tags: reactjs

All I want to do is to add `componentDidMount()` method to original component. I don't want to change anything else in it. How do I extend it?

I need something like this:

```
import FooComponent from 'foo-component';

class MyComponent extends FooComponent {
    componentDidMount() {
        // my custom behavior
    }
    render() {
        super()
    }
}

module.exports = MyComponent;
```

Answer (score 2):

You only have to rewrite the methods you want to change.

```
class MyComponent extends FooComponent {
    componentDidMount() {
        // my custom behavior
    }
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/525/)